# async.queue drain function won't fire

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, queue, async.js

I had an async.queue implementation on my node js app but the queue.drain function recently stopped firing at all.

I suspected the issue was related to await statements I have inside task functions but I also am able to reproduce the issue using the sample on [async docs](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue)

```
const async = require('async')

var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
  console.log('hello ' + task.name);
  callback();
}, 1);

q.drain(function() {
  console.log('all items have been processed');
});

q.push({name: 'bar'});
q.push({name: 'foo'}, function(err) {
  console.log('finished processing foo');
});
```

This will output the following on my console but not the drain statement. So is there something I am missing?

> hello bar
>
> hello foo
>
> finished processing foo

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing your issue with your given example. drain seems to work when I run locally. This is with Node 10.15 and async 3.2. What versions are you using?

Comment: node 10.16 and "async": "^3.2.0",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly, converting the drain function into an arrow function resolved the issue.

```
q.drain = function () {
  console.log('all items have been processed');
}

q.drain(() => {
  console.log('all items have been processed');
}
```

Comment: You did not convert the function. The first one assigns a function and overwrites drain and the second one calls drain with a parameter your function